# What is the music style from a lot of 70's Japanese anime or *tokusatsu* series called?

Tags: identify-this-genre, japan

> What is the music style from a lot of 70's Japanese anime or [*tokusatsu*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokusatsu) series called?

I'm trying to find a term that includes all that type of music, as a lot of them sound kinda similar. I don't know very well how to explain why they all sound that similar but listening to them is enough.

For example these 3 videos:

- [*Devilman* (1972)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L5n2bkCZvvY)
- [*Himitsu Sentai Gorenger* (1975-77)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gbuEg2v9Arg)
- [*Kamen Rider* (1971)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V1PA3Arxevs)

There are quite a lot of other examples which sound similar from series from the 70's.

What is this style (I guess it has to be considered one) called?

Answer (score 2):

I tried to think of something famous with a similar spirit, and I came up with [Don't Let Me Be Misunderstood](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-hwiCkU73NA) from the Kill Bill soundtrack. The vocals there are a lot more on the funk side (whereas the singers in your examples are ballad-like), but everthing else seems close enough.

The [Wiki for that song](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_Let_Me_Be_Misunderstood) says that the Kill Bill version is a [four-on-the-floor disco](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_on_the_floor_(music)) arrangement. So the broad answer to your question is **disco**.

If you are not convinced, listen to [Michel LeGrand's Disco Magic Concorde](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vkpMr4cMDkQ) from 1978, and imagine enthusiastic Japanese voices singing over it :)

I would still be interested to know if the combination of the ballad voices with the disco base is a subgenre of disco (like in your examples and in Michel LeGrand's piece)...

Answer (score 2):

These songs are a pastiche of popular late 60s and early 70s pop styles.  The first has a distinctly [Western](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tgvxu8QY01s) feel, perhaps via the [Italo-Western](https://youtu.be/DT1NJwEi6nw?t=1m25s) style innovated by Ennio Morricone.

@Alvaro is correct that the second and third tracks are perhaps best characterized as disco derivatives, but they are closer to 70s [Euro Disco](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euro_disco) than to US disco.  [Euro Disco](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1IMmdpYzHDE), as exemplified by groups like [Boney M](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yD8DcgpLp_w) and [ABBA](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sj_9CiNkkn4), has that characteristic 4-on-the-floor disco beat, but less of the direct African-American funk influences than US disco, and more of the ballad-style vocals.

With all that said, I strongly suspect that this music isn't anime specific, but represents what pop styles generally sounded like in Japan in the 70s.  For that reason, the best answer may well be **[70s J-Pop](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yVvex56mgPw)**.